# Create custom order sortby based on array of id

Tags: wp-query, order

im working on custom order sortby based on array of id from drag drop post..
i manage to get the id's from saved settings..

for example i have

```
Array (
    [0] => 8701
    [1] => 11301
    [2] => 8999
    [3] => 9000
    [4] => 9137
    [5] => 9023
    [6] => 9043
    [7] => 9020
    [8] => 9081
    [9] => 9109
    [10] => 8984
    [11] => 8967
)
```

but the wordpress keep sorting it by id..i want to query it by the same order.

Comment: How are you querying the posts?

Comment: if i got this right..i can set an offset too right?

$samp = array (
      'post_type'              => 'product',
      'posts_per_page'         => 12,
      'post__in'              => $init_ids_arr,
    );
$sample = new WP_Query();
$sample->query($samp);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you want to order by [`post__in`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters):

```
$samp = array ( 
    'post_type'      => 'product', 
    'posts_per_page' => 12, 
    'post__in'       => $init_ids_arr, 
    'orderby'        => 'post__in',        // <-- Try this to fix the order
);
```

We might also want to skip the *sticky posts* with:

```
'ignore_sticky_posts' => true,
```

If we want to display all of the user-selected posts, then we could use:

```
$samp = array ( 
    'post_type'           => 'product', 
    'post__in'            => $init_ids_arr, 
    'nopaging'            => true,              // <-- No paging 
    'ignore_sticky_posts' => true,              // <-- Avoid injected sticky posts 
    'orderby'             => 'post__in',        // <-- Keep user defined order
);
```

where we added the `nopaging` attribute to remove the `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` and `LIMIT` parts of the generated SQL query.

We should remember to validate the user input, before we run the query.
Like making sure the `$init_ids_arr` isn't an empty array otherwise we get the default WHERE part of the query. We also want to make sure it's only integers and we don't want to query huge number of posts.

Comment: whoaaa works like charm!, i never though that 'orderby' => 'post__in' is possible

Thank you!

Comment: yes the orderby `post__in` is handy. It' uses the `FIELD()` ordering in SQL. It was added in WordPress version 3.5